# C# Console project with Migrations Error: The entry point exited without ever building an IHost

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I've been trying to create a console app that handles migrations, following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=vs, but unfortunately it's not working as expected.

In the Main app I added this:

```
 services.AddDbContext<ADbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                     x => x.MigrationsAssembly("PA.Seeding")
                ));
```

Then in the Console App (PA), The App Class is this:

```
private static ServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public static void Init()
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            IConfiguration configuration;

            configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            serviceCollection.AddSingleton(configuration);
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton<MigrationsHandler>();
            serviceCollection.AddDbContext<ADbContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            _serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        }

        public static void StartMigrations()
        {
            var dbContext = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ADbContext>();
            dbContext.Database.Migrate();
        }
```

When running the command:

```
Add-Migration NewMigration -Project PA.Seeding
```

This is the error I get:

```
An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: The entry point exited without ever building an IHost.
Unable to create an object of type 'ADbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Do you have `var app = builder.Build();`? The `Build` method returns a `WebApplication` which implements `IHost`.

Comment: @IvanGechev are there any other options ? I'd like it to just run the migrations and then stop. I followed the link https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728. But it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Used WebApplicationBuilder, and works just fine. But it's strange using it for a non web application.